# Azure Load balancing to Multiple Sites with Disaster Recovery

Tags: azure, load-balancing, iaas, internal-load-balancer

I am trying to configure applications on 2 different Azure sites having their local load balancing capabilities. I can use Traffic manager to distribute the traffic and have weighted routing to force everything to my primary site.

But i want this to occur automatically where i can map a service pointing to the internal load balancers at both sites and evaluate the sites are up and running or not to decide where to forward the traffic. This will allow me not to manually configure the Traffic Manager in case of disaster.

Note : The services are hosted on IIS on IaaS VMs. ILB1 and ILB2 are respective loadbalancer for Site1 and Site2.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, we can't add internal load balancer as traffic manager endpoints.

> But I want this to occur automatically where I can map a service
>   pointing to the internal load balancers at both sites and evaluate them
>   sites are up and running or not to decide where to forward the
>   traffic.

By default, we can set multiple sites around the world with traffic manager, traffic manager will probe the health of all sites, forward network traffic to the right site.

We can use traffic manager profile to manage network traffic, traffic Manager profiles use traffic-routing methods to control the distribution of traffic to your cloud services or website endpoints.

For example, we create website 1 on site 1 (primary site), create website 2 on site 2. If we use the weighted method, network traffic will to site 1. When site 1 is down, traffic manager will know site 1 was down, will route network traffic to site 2.

**Traffic manager works as a DNS level Load Balancer**, it will route network to the available site by default.

About traffic manager probe settings, we can via the Azure portal to modify it, like this:

[image]

By the way, if you want to use traffic manager, we can add public IP address to traffic manager endpoint.

---

**Update**:

As a workaround, we can deploy a S2S VPN between two locations, and use Haproxy to work as load balancer, then add two VMs to public load balancer, like this:

[image]

We can use Haproxy to set primary website, more information about Haproxy, please refer to this [link](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt).

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for the response. I later found out the complexity with traffic manager with our implementation. I want to avoid the entire external interaction if possible. All the servers are in VNet but they need DR capability. I couldn't find the service which will be able to distribute the load between 2 ILB over 2 sites. The external or public endpoint will be created by another service which can already point to our ILB. Do you have any idea, anything satisfying my requirement? want to avoid having Appgateway or another service for traffic manager. Everything should be internal

Comment: @Linu1988 As far as I know, there is no Azure service can achieve this directly, as a workaround, we can create S2S VPN between location 1 and location 2, then create two VMs and deploy Haproxy on them, and add private IP addresses of two ILB to Haproxy endpoint, then create a internet load balancer before two VMs. we can use Haproxy to set the primary website, in this way, we can achieve that.

Comment: @Linu1988 Please let me know if you need more help. Also, if it helps, please don' forget to accept it as an answer so that other community will be benefited, thanks:)

Comment: Thank you Jason, I accept the answers and there is so much can be for the problem I have at hand. I will reach MS with a ticket for further implementation challenge. For now I have few more options which I had explored.